# Apple Watch Simulator Does Not Work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, apple-watch

I've followed the steps in some of the tutorials I found. If I create a new project, make some changes to the storyboard and just run Apple Watch simulator, I see my changes. It runs normally but when I try to integrate it in my existing app, nothing happens. It's just all black and my app doesn't run as well. Did I miss any additional setup if I'm going to integrate it in an existing app?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple watch simulator issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201559/apple-watch-simulator-issue)

Answer (score 1):

I've had many issues while running the apple watch simulator, but I manage to use it most of the time.

(Note : every line is a different strategy, they're independent from each other)

- Start your app on an iphone simulator without actually compiling your app (just clic on the icon you've compiled in the past), then run the applewatch app target on that same simulator
- Sometimes I get a strange error, cleaning/restarting the simulator tends to help
- Start your app -> load the external display -> restart your app
- Running the parent with the external display already loaded