# Cannot run any Apple iWatch app in XCode 6.3.1 simulator

Tags: ios, apple-watch, xcode6.3.1

Trying to start any project for Apple Watch in my XCode 6.3.1 simulation (5/6/6+) and always (for all example project) get "Waiting to attach" and black screen of Apple iWatch simulator. Never see that its working on. Does any one has the same issue? 
I have checked also [Apple watch simulator issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201559/apple-watch-simulator-issue) but did not find any proper solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple watch simulator issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201559/apple-watch-simulator-issue)

Comment: There are many questions on SO about this, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201559/apple-watch-simulator-issue

Comment: I checked all of them no one helped.